# Editing table data using php, PDO, and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, pdo

I have a data table that displays the `counter` table in the database.

It has **create** and **edit** buttons, each linked to a pop-up modal. The create button works fine, but I'm having an issue with the edit button.

When I click the edit button in a row, it's supposed to retrieve the data from the database table and display them in the text fields of the **edit modal**.

The data gets retrieved without any issues. But, the only thing that gets displayed in the **edit modal** is the `id`. The rest of the data gets displayed in the **create modal**.

I tried to find the error but I couldn't figure it out yet.

This is the `counter` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `counter` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's how the code goes.

`create modal`

```
 <div id="addModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Counter</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="form-data" novalidate>

                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label>Counter Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Status</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="1" checked required>
                            <label for="avtive">Active</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="0">
                            <label for="avtive">Inactive</label><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" />
                            <input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="Add Counter" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

`edit modal`

```
 <div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Counter</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="edit-form-data" novalidate>
                        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label>Counter Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Status</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="1" checked required>
                            <label for="avtive">Active</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="0">
                            <label for="avtive">Inactive</label><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" />
                            <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="Edit Counter" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

`script`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //edit ajax request
        $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(e) {
            // console.log("working");
            e.preventDefault();
            edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../php/admin-action.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    edit_id: edit_id
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    data = JSON.parse(response);
                    // console.log(data);
                    $("#id").val(data.id);
                    $("#name").val(data.name);
                    $("#desc").val(data.description);
                    $("#status").val(data.status);

                },
                error: function(response) {
                    toastr.error('Error detected while adding, Please try again later!');
                }
            })
        })

        // update ajax request
        $("#update").click(function(e) {
            if ($("#edit-form-data")[0].checkValidity()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../php/admin-action.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#edit-form-data").serialize() + "&action=update",
                    success: function(response) {
                        toastr.success('Counter edited successfully!');
                        setInterval(2000);
                        $("#editModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#edit-form-data")[0].reset();
                        showAllCounters();
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        toastr.error('Error detected while editing, Please try again later!');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

`admin-action.php`

```
// handle view counter list
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'view') {
    $output = '';

    $data = $db->read_counter();
    if ($db->totalRowCount_counter() > 0) {
        $output .= '<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Counter</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Updated Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output .= ' <tr>
            <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['created_at'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['updated_at'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>
            <td class="project-actions text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm viewBtn" id="' . $row['id'] . '">
                <i class="fas fa-folder">
                </i>
                View
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm editBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" id="' . $row['id'] . '">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">
                </i>
                Edit
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dltBtn" id="' . $row['id'] . '">
                <i class="fas fa-trash">
                </i>
                Delete
            </a>
        </td></tr>';
        }

        $output .= '</tbody></table>';
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo '<h3 class="text-center text-secondary mt-5">:(No counters present in the database!)</h3>';
    }
    // print_r($data);
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'insert') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $db->insert_counter($name, $desc, $status);
}

if (isset($_POST['edit_id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['edit_id'];

    $row = $db->getCounterByID($id);
    echo json_encode($row);
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $db->update_counter($id, $name, $desc, $status);
}
```

`admin-db.php`

```
 public function getCounterById($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM counter WHERE id = $id";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}

public function update_counter($id, $name, $desc, $status)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE counter SET name=:name, desc=:desc,status=:status WHERE id = :id ";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['name' => $name, 'desc' => $desc, 'status' => $status, 'id' => $id]);

    return true;
}
```

I'm posting all of the code because I'm not exactly sure where the problem is. Apologies for making it so long.

Comment: Note that `$sql = "SELECT * FROM counter WHERE id = $id";` permits sql injection (ie is insecure and not a correct use of a prepared statement)

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST OF ALL**

You should not use the same value for HTML `id` attribute. You used in both create and edit form the same ids for the input fields. The value of the `id` attribute has to be unique on the entire HTML page, even if some parts are hidden.

**CURRENT BEHAVIOR**

Your create form does not have an input field with attribute `id='id'`, that is why the corresponding input field is filled after the ajax request.But the other 4 input fields exist in both forms. Because the create form is placed before the update form in your HTML content, the input fields of create form are filled.

**SOLUTION**

Please change your success function of your `.editBtn` click handler like this:

```js
success: function(response) {
    data = JSON.parse(response);
    // console.log(data);
    let $form = $('#edit-form-data');
    let radioId = data.status === "1" ? "#editStatusActive" : "#editStatusInactive";

    $form.find("input[id='id']").val(data.id);
    $form.find("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
    $form.find("[name='desc']").val(data.description);
    $form.find(radioId).click();
},
},
```

Then update the form group for `status` in your update form like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Status</label><br>
    
    <input type="radio" name="status" id="editStatusActive" value="1" checked required>
    <label for="editStatusActive">Active</label><br>

    <input type="radio" name="status" id="editStatusInactive" value="0">
    <label for="editStatusInactive">Inactive</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours. Now the name field works fine, but the description doesn't. Is there something wrong with the naming? I think I must've mixed up `desc` and `description` somewhere...

Comment: And the update function is not working now either...

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha About description: How is the field in your AJAX request defined? description or desc? Another problem could be, that description is a `<textarea>`  element and settings its content via `$().val(...)` may not work. You can try with `$(...).text(data.description)` instead. What do you mean exactly with `update function is not working now either` ?

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha Let me analyse your admin_action.php.

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha You mean nothing happens when you press the Update-Button in your edit-dialog? You have then most possibly a JavaScript error. Look at the Browser console please and post the error message if exists. I believe the check `$("#edit-form-data")[0].checkValidity()` does not work. So your edit form values are not valid somehow.

Comment: Yes, nothing happens when I click the edit button. I checked the console, but it doesn't show any error either.

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha Ok. There are some mistake on setting the values of the fields as I mentioned in my solution. I will update my solution and tell you when I am done. Please give me some time.

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha Now it should work. Please do not make unnecessary assumptions. For instance that you could set the values of various input elements like input field, textarea, radio button etc. just using one jQ function call. There are some differences for instance in case of radio button. Please be sure that you use the correct jQuery API method to set/get the values. And last but not the least: Please rename the `id` attribute of the other input elements (also labels for attr) in your edit form as I did it with the status field. Just prepent `edit` to the id an capitalize the next word

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha Please let me know, if it worked. If yes then upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Now the description field gets filled. But the edit button still doesn't work.

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha You have to find out what is exactly happening when you click the update button. Put following alert() calls into your update click handler: Put `alert('after preventDefault');` for checking if `validityCheck()` return true. Then put `alert('In ajax success handler');` and `alert('In ajax error handler');`. Then observe which alert() call is executed after you clicked the update button.